# polymer iron-input separate validate message required and pattern

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am using form validation with patterns, on required fields. When the user opens the form, it all shows the error message that belongs to not matching the pattern. But I want the users only to see the 'required' message when the form field is still empty.

How can I accomplish this? 
The input is simple, for only numbers and letters:

```
<paper input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}" error-message="Only use numbers an letters, max 30 characters" maxlength="30" required auto-validate></paper-input>
```

It shows "Only use numbers an letters, max 30 characters" in red ofcourse, but initially I want it to show a 'required' message.

Comment: https://github.com/youssef06/polymer-login-form/blob/master/login-form/js/login-form.js   check the "email" property there and its 'placeholder'.. separates the 2 concerns u r interest in.

Comment: wow, need to wrap my head around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. You could change the `label` attribute to say `Please enter your name (required)` or you could use the `placeholder` attribute to have some placeholder text in the input when it is empty which could also say that this field is required.